# Trim Whitespace from AsyncListView of a RSS Feed

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, rss, trim

This is some Flex code from a Flex mobile project. I want to load Rss Feed into an IList which has errorneous white space. So far i know of **Stringutil.trim(String)**. But im stuck where I should use it to make the list work. Please advise.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:studierende="services.studierende.*"
    xmlns:allgemein="services.allgemein.*"
    xmlns:veranstaltung="services.veranstaltung.*"
    xmlns:wissenschaft="services.wissenschaft.*"
    overlayControls="false">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.net.dns.AAAARecord;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.utils.StringUtil;

        protected function openmenu(event:MouseEvent):void
        {}
        protected function reload(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            asynclist.removeAll();
            getDataResult.token = feed1.getData();
        }

        protected function loadRSS(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getDataResult.token = feed1.getData();
            //I guess here is a good place to trim the whitespaces. But how ?

        }


        protected function loadfeed(event:MouseEvent,rid:Number):void
        {
            var rssid:Number = rid;
            switch(rssid)
            {
                case 0:
                    asynclist.removeAll();
                    getDataResult.token = feed1.getData();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    asynclist.removeAll();
                    getDataResult.token = feed2.getData();
                    break;
                 case 2:
                    asynclist.removeAll();
                    getDataResult.token = feed3.getData();
                    break; 
                 case 3:
                    asynclist.removeAll();
                    getDataResult.token = feed4.getData();
                    break; 
            }
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
    <allgemein:Allgemein id="feed1"/>
    <studierende:Studierende id="feed2"/>
    <veranstaltung:Veranstaltung id="feed3"/>
    <wissenschaft:Wissenschaft id="feed4"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:navigationContent>
    <s:Button id="menubtn" label="Menu" click="openmenu(event)"/>
</s:navigationContent>
<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button id="reloadbtn" label="RELOAD" click="reload(event)"/>
</s:actionContent>
    <s:List id="list" left="10" right="10" top="50" bottom="10" creationComplete="loadRSS(event)"
            itemRenderer="icItemRender" labelField="title">
        <s:AsyncListView id="asynclist" list="{getDataResult.lastResult}" />
    </s:List>
<s:HGroup x="10" y="10" width="748" height="32">
    <s:Button height="32" label="Allgemein" fontSize="12" click="loadfeed(event,0)"/>
    <s:Button height="32" label="Studierende" fontSize="12" click="loadfeed(event,1)"/>
    <s:Button height="32" label="Veranstaltung" fontSize="12" click="loadfeed(event,2)"/>
    <s:Button height="32" label="Wissenschaft" fontSize="12" click="loadfeed(event,3)"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to trim the whitespace from the title that is displayed in each element of the list.

The easiest way is probably to use a labelFunction.  Set it on your list, like this:

```
<s:List id="list" left="10" right="10" top="50" bottom="10" creationComplete="loadRSS(event)"
        itemRenderer="icItemRender" labelFunction="myLabelFunction">
```

Noticed, I removed your labelField declaration.  The function should be something like this:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function myLabelFunction(item:Object):String {
            return Stringutil.trim(item.title);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

You could also create a custom itemRenderer to achieve the same end result.

Comment: Actually it is the description which needs trimming. I have a look for maybe contentFunction or so and apply your solution...thanks

Comment: @user981027 Based in the code you shared; there is no description being displayed anywhere.  I did not notice you are specifying an itemRenderer.  Please share that code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved things with help of flextras via a custom item renderer

```
package
{
import com.adobe.fiber.styles.Style;

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

import mx.utils.StringUtil;

import spark.components.Button;
import spark.components.IconItemRenderer;
import spark.components.Image;
import spark.components.LabelItemRenderer;
import spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField;


/**
 * 
 * ASDoc comments for this item renderer class
 * 
 */
public class asListItemRenderer extends IconItemRenderer
{
    private var titleDisplay:StyleableTextField;
    private var msgDisplay:StyleableTextField;
    private var link:String;
    private var readon:Image;
    private var stagewebview:StageWebView;
    private var warning:AlertPopUp;
    public function asListItemRenderer()
    {
        //TODO: implement function
        super();
        super.labelField = "title";
        super.messageField = "description";

    }

    /**
     * @private
     *
     * Override this setter to respond to data changes
     */
    override public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        /*super.data = value;*/
        titleDisplay.text = value.title;
        msgDisplay.text = trimMessage(value);
        link = value.link;
        // the data has changed.  push these changes down in to the 
        // subcomponents here           
    } 

    /**
     * @private
     * 
     * Override this method to create children for your item renderer 
     */ 
    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        titleDisplay = createDataField(false, false, "bold");
        addChild(titleDisplay);
        msgDisplay = createDataField(true, true);
        addChild(msgDisplay);
        readon = new Image();
        readon.source="assets/readmore_32px.png";
        readon.width=32;
        readon.height=32;
        addChild(readon);
        readon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,openlink);

        // super.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,openlink);
        // create any additional children for your item renderer here
    }

    private function openlink(e:Event):void
    {


        /*if(StageWebView.isSupported==true){
            stagewebview=new StageWebView();
            stagewebview.viewPort=new Rectangle(0,0,stage.width,stage.height);
            stagewebview.stage=this.stage;
            stagewebview.loadURL(link);
        }else{
            warning = new AlertPopUp();
            warning.open(this);
        }*/
    }
    /**
     * @private
     * 
     * Override this method to change how the item renderer 
     * sizes itself. For performance reasons, do not call 
     * super.measure() unless you need to.
     */ 
    override protected function measure():void
    {
        //super.measure();
        // measure all the subcomponents here and set measuredWidth, measuredHeight, 
        // measuredMinWidth, and measuredMinHeight 
        measuredHeight = measuredMinHeight = 120;
        measuredWidth = measuredMinWidth = unscaledWidth;
    }

    /**
     * @private
     * 
     * Override this method to change how the background is drawn for 
     * item renderer.  For performance reasons, do not call 
     * super.drawBackground() if you do not need to.
     */
    override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, 
                                               unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.drawBackground(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        // do any drawing for the background of the item renderer here              
    }

    /**
     * @private
     *  
     * Override this method to change how the background is drawn for this 
     * item renderer. For performance reasons, do not call 
     * super.layoutContents() if you do not need to.
     */

    private function createDataField(multiline:Boolean = false, wordWrap:Boolean = false, style:String = "normal"):StyleableTextField
    {
        var labelField:StyleableTextField = new StyleableTextField();
        labelField.styleName = this;
        labelField.editable = false;
        labelField.selectable = false;
        labelField.multiline = multiline;
        labelField.wordWrap = wordWrap;
        labelField.setStyle("fontSize", 14);
        labelField.setStyle("color", 0x333333);
        labelField.setStyle("fontWeight", style);
        return labelField;
    }

    override protected function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, 
                                               unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        setElementPosition(titleDisplay, 10, 10);
        setElementSize(titleDisplay, unscaledWidth, measuredMinHeight);
        setElementPosition(msgDisplay, 10, titleDisplay.y + 30);
        setElementSize(msgDisplay, unscaledWidth-50, measuredHeight);
        setElementPosition(readon,unscaledWidth-32,44);
        setElementSize(readon,32,32);
        // super.layoutContents(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        // layout all the subcomponents here   

    }
    private function trimMessage(item:Object):String {
        return StringUtil.trim(item.description);
    }

}
}
```